# How does browser understands type of the file to download

Tags: http

In Chrome when I provide below url it downloads docx file,

https://bob.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/15081992/biography.docx?api=v2

But in curl with same URL it downloads html file,
curl -0 -u bob2000:passbob2000 "https://bob.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/15081992/biography.docx?api=v2" --output biography.docx

How to make curl or wget to download Docx

Comment: What does the downloaded html file contain? Might give you some clues.

Comment: Below lines it has,      
HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized "The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource"

Comment: It looks like your trying to use basic auth with your request, atlassian.net might not support that. I'm not sure what auth types curl supports, but I'd start there.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be generic, since browser is able to do it . My thought was it is still generic rule but something else for sure what curl does

Comment: Found solution seems like page gets moved so with wget using "-L" option it works fine.